# How to retrieve from two tables with same foreign key repeated more than once?

Tags: c#-4.0

How to display the data of tables that are linked by a primary key and foreign key where the foreign key of the data repeats?
For ex. I have two tables, `ParentTable` and `Childtable`.
The primary key of `ParentTable` acts as the foreign key of `ChildTable`.
There are more than one record with same `ParentId` in `ChildTable`. How to retrieve them and display in a single Grid or List or any type of view?

Comment: What database server do you use? Is it a web or winform app? Could you be more specific in your question, you don't know how to query or retrieve the result or bind it to a list...

Answer (score 0):

As for the query: if you are using Oracle you may use a [CONNECT BY statement](http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/trees.html) in your query; otherwise you can just use a JOIN on the foreign key to retrieve the list of couples Parent-Child and handle them in your C# business logic.

As for the presentation: this is the classic tree structure, so you may find a [Treeview](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/TreeViewExample.htm) useful.